# How to extract extract from outlook.live.com email (which provides a link not a traditional attachment)

Tags: outlook, sendgrid, email-attachments

I have a sendgrid "inbound parser" which sends an email to my server as a webhook.
The payload includes an attachments section like this:

```
"sender_ip":"40.92.63.181",
   "attachments":"1",
   "attachment-info":"{\"attachment1\":{\"filename\":\"Bidfood_Australia_Limited_Purchase_Order_P7565077.pdf\",\"name\":\"Bidfood_Australia_Limited_Purchase_Order_P7565077.pdf\",\"type\":\"application/pdf\"}}"
}
```

If I send such an email from outlook.live.com to say a gmail account, the email presents the attachment as a link:

like this:

https://1drv.ms/b/s!Aj5BJ---------FsjxIuqdiwj

In the payload I received, I can not see how to get this link.

---

Update: In gmail when I view "original" (the message source), there is this section:

--*000_SYZP282MB34292E8F3450F91FC11B3DC6B94FASYZP282MB3429AUSP*
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

```
[https://res-h3.public.cdn.office.net/assets/mail/file-icon/png/pdf_16x16.p=
ng]Bidfood_Australia_Limited_Purchase_Order_P7565077.pdf<https://1drv.ms/b/=
s!Aj5BJW-----xIuqdiwj>
```

so it ishould be there ... but this content is not in the payload sent by Sendgrid.